# ContentResolver takePersistableUriPermission with zero flag. Why?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-contentresolver

According to official documentation parameter `takeFlags` of method of `ContentResolver` [`takePersistableUriPermission`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) may be zero. Why?

Also in guide [Persist permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions)

```
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

This code means that `intent.getFlags()` can return zero and we will take zero permission.
So, in this case I must call to user with message "can not take permission" but why it may happen? There is no information.

Comment: `This code means that intent.getFlags() can return zero` No. Please read better. What you can read in your link is that if you call takePersistableUriPermission() the parameter takeFlags may be zero.

Comment: You cannot always take persistable uri permissions. (Please read again: quote: Only URI permissions granted with Intent#FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION can be persisted. I). It depends on the content provider if it is possible. And also the used intent action.